# How to find how many functions does a package in R have? e.g. how many functions does "MASS" package has?

Tags: r, function, package

I want to know how many functions does "MASS" package has? Could you please tell me a command that I can use to know this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you load MASS library, try this: 
`length(ls('package:MASS'))` to get a count of all objects

use mode param `ls.str()` to change what you get back:

- for functions: `length(ls.str('package:MASS', mode='function'))`